# T-SQL OUTPUT DELETED columns by information schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

[image]

Whenewher I'm removing some records from TableFirst I need to insert deleted record data into TableSecond. But they have different number of columns.

Is it possible to output deleted values of common columns using information schema(except Id of course) in delete statement?

```
DELETE FROM TableFirst 
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO TableSecond
WHERE Id = 1
```

I'm trying to avoid naming each column (I'll have up to 50 columns in my project).

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Including the `CREATE` statements rather than screenshots allows the rest of us to have a go at solving your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the way to do it with the dynamic sql, we just need to compose query, where we can select all required column names using information schema and execute it.

Get column names first:

```
DECLARE @ColumnNamesTable Table([Name] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @ColumnNamesTable
SELECT [Name] FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'TableFirst') AND [Name] <> 'Id' 
INTERSECT
SELECT [Name] FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'TableSecond')
```

Compose OUTPUT DELETED and column name strings:

```
DECLARE @OutputDeleted NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @OutputDeleted = STUFF((SELECT ', DELETED.' + Name FROM @ColumnNamesTable  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1,'')
SELECT @ColumnNames = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name FROM @ColumnNamesTable  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1,'')
```

Compose query:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX), @MyId INT = 5;
SELECT @Query = CONCAT('DELETE FROM dbo.TableFirst OUTPUT', ' ', @OutputDeleted, ' ','INTO dbo.TableSecond(', @ColumnNames,') WHERE Id = ', @MyId)
```

Finaly we just execute the composed query:

```
exec sp_executesql @Query;
```

But we can get issues when there are some FKs.

Comment: You should add more detail to this answer as it's not very clear.

Comment: @CodyKonior done. Or do you think to name each of 50 columns is better option?

Comment: You should be careful about using uppercase in system tables like SYS.COLUMNS because it will break on case sensitive collations. Regarding FKs there are system tables to either search for those too or to alter them to set them to null or cascade the delete (I do this for temporal tables as they don't support cascades). But it's best practice to name every column - otherwise (for example) views can break on changes if you don't refresh them - and running this dynamic code every time will be slower than doing it hardcoded. During development it's okay though.